# A free widget that import contacts from yahoo, gmail, etc

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I want to make users of my website share my website through email. But sending email manually to everyone is boring and no one will do it.

Is there a FREE widget that i can put in my website and it connects will yahoo, hotmail or gmail and just let the user select the contacts and send the email through my website.

right now i have a simple email option on my website that allows putting emails manually.(at the top

www.omenaa.ws

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: i have tried cloudsponge widget to import contacts but its only free for localhost websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sugest you go to http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools#sthash.8AR919Pu.dpbs and use thire simple config eg;
select "website" in section 1,
select "butons" in section 2,
then add/remove the buttons you want in section 3,
then continue to get the code.

although they give options for nearly every type of social media here is a simple email only mockup.

```
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-e375eb64-24ef-2ffa-db93-68c3a06b249a", doNotHash: true, doNotCopy: true, hashAddressBar: true});</script>
```

see it in action  > http://jsfiddle.net/z3yfp/ notice that once you click the mail icon there is a section that give the option for google contacts ands yahoo contacts.

Corrected link ^^^

Comment: sorry, but the fiddle link is not the right one. can you double check?

Comment: sharethis only has import options from yahoo and google. How can i get hotmail, AOL, etc

Comment: I believe hotmail don't 'really' support the exporting of contacts like google dose, there are some that have access to the relevant api's to do so but i dont think its that openly shared. Bit in the list of other options to share there is messenger (msn) which is directly linked through hotmail... I wouldn't bother about AOL either.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt something like that exists or if it does to be free, in the best case scenario you will have to write it by yourself!

Since everyone uses facebook these days, why don't you create a basic app that logs in as the user and gets the emails from the user's friends? I bet something like that in your website will be more popular than hotmail and yahoo integration! :)

Comment: yes, i already have FB sharing but i want t0o do email to just in case they don't use FB